# .NET GetProcessById: When is InvalidOperationException thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, invalidoperationexception

According to the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_GetProcessById_System_Int32_):

> **InvalidOperationException**
>   The process was not started by this object.

I am simply unable to imagine what this description should mean. How should I treat it or explain it to the user?

Comment: I think it means the process you're trying to get is owned by a different user/computer so whichever is user running the .NET program doesn't have access to it

Comment: I think it's a documentation bug since [it doesn't throw InvalidOperationException](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,1512)

Comment: Thanks, where can I report the bug?

Comment: @KnorxThieus Use the [Feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid?view=netframework-4.7.2#feedback) section at the bottom of the documentation.